# json not giving back the proper result from database array

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

I am getting back two rows from my query, I tested it in phpadmin.

In firebug I can only see the data from one row.

**What could be wrong that I don't see?**

```
$data = mysql_fetch_assoc($r);

        }
    }

    header('Content-type: application/json');           
    $output = array(
    "check" => $check,
    "users" => $data,
    "testnumberoffrows" => $number
    );

    echo json_encode($output);
```

in the ajaxfunction

```
if( data.check ){
    var user = data.users;
    console.log(user);
```

thanks, Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql_fetch_assoc()` fetches only *one* row.  You need to loop until it returns `FALSE`, building up an output array.

Something like this:

```
while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)) !== FALSE) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: thanks, I completely missed that, I am giving myself headeaches

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
    $got=array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r)) {
        array_push($got, $row);
    }

    mysql_free_result($r);

    header('Content-type: application/json');            
    $output = array( 
        "check" => $check, 
        "users" => $data, 
        "testnumberoffrows" => $number 
    ); 

    echo json_encode($output);
```